# Getting issue with fetching details in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my table having tax details:

**Image of records in table**

[image]

I would like to fetch details of a tax record when I have an integer (say, 2500) between the `start_range_cost` and `end_range_cost`.

My current SQL using 3000 as an example:

```
SELECT * FROM `hotel_tax_details` 
 WHERE `start_range_cost`>=3000 AND `end_range_cost`<=3000
```

Comment: Pleae show your code that you have made so far

Comment: Can you please show your code effort what you have tried so far? add that in your question.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `hotel_tax_details` WHERE `start_range_cost`>=3000 AND `end_range_cost`<=3000

Comment: Please paste your code so, we have identified your issue where you stuck

Comment: SELECT * FROM hotel_tax_details WHERE start_range_cost>=2500 AND end_range_cost<=2500 For set the post value in start range and end range

Comment: Of course you fetch nothing as nothing is in your criteria `WHERE start_range_cost>=3000 AND end_range_cost<=3000`. Could you double confirm if your criteria is correct?

Comment: There's a basic lack of... well... let's call it attention... here

Comment: @Strawberry to be fair, once they added the query I had to double-take it to catch the error.  As long as humans write code, there will be bugs, many simplistic once you see it, yet sometimes difficult to catch -- can't tell you how many times I've stared at failing code, to have some newbie be like, oh, you're using a bitwise AND `&` vs. a logical condition `&&`.  Our brains see patterns better than details, which is why it's useful to ask for help and we shouldn't belittle others doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Based solely on the query in your OP and the records in your image nothing would be returned.  It would only return if both `start_range_cost` AND `end_range_cost` were exactly `3000` which none of the records match, but this is just because you've got the `<` and `>` signs flipped around.  Try using `BETWEEN`, I feel it's less prone to comparison mistakes if you're upper and lower bounds inclusive in your comparison.

Assuming:

- `2500` is the number in the range searching for from your example
- You want to be lower and upper bound inclusive (base on your image, it looks like it)

You can use `BETWEEN` to make this clearer:

```
SELECT * FROM hotel_tax_details 
  WHERE 2500 BETWEEN start_range_cost AND end_range_cost;
```

You could also fix the original query and correct the comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM `hotel_tax_details` 
 WHERE `start_range_cost`<=2500 AND `end_range_cost`>=2500
```

Comment: Seemly he wants `start_range_cost ` >= 2500 & `end_range_cost` <= 2500.

Comment: @CKWong  I'm assuming from the image (since the bounds `start_range_cost` and `end_range_cost` don't over lap`) they're looking for a single record returned.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT * FROM hotel_tax_details WHERE 2500 BETWEEN start_range_cost AND end_range_cost
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me solution